# HipChat integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, hipchat

I'm trying to add the [HipChat plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/hipchat-plugin) to my Jenkins builds, but it doesn't post anything.

In the global configuration I've set the HipChat server to `api.hipchat.com`, added an API token und default room ID, set the build server URL to `https://xxx.ci.cloudbees.com/` and the send as name to `Jenkins`.

In the build job configuration I've tried setting the same room ID and leaving the field blank (so it should use the default). I've activated all notify checkboxes and added `HipChat Notifications` as the (only) post-build action.

However, I'm not receiving any build updates in the given room. So I've added a custom Jenkins logger, logging `ALL` from `jenkins.plugins.hipchat`. For every build I start, I get a single log entry like this:

```
Aug 28, 2014 6:08:20 PM INFO jenkins.plugins.hipchat.HipChatNotifier$HipChatJobProperty prebuild
Invoking Started...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I could debug this further?

PS: I'm running on Cloudbees — not sure if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Hipchat notifier plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HipChat+Plugin) uses the HipChat API v1, not the newer API v2.  I had the same problem while trying to use a v2 token.

Try creating an admin token in Hipchat for Jenkins (e.g., https://my-hipchat-group.hipchat.com/admin/api) instead of creating a room token (e.g., https://my-hipchat-group.hipchat.com/admin/rooms/tokens/665113).

I was able to get the HipChat API v2 token working with a manually built hpi from the https://github.com/yagince/hipchat-notifier-plugin project.

Comment: which means it won't work for hosted environments like cloudbees :(

Comment: This answer is outdated now. The Jenkins Hipchat plugin now supports Hipchat's v2 API and Hipchat as deprecated the v1 API.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been addressed in the 0.1.9 and newer versions of the hipchat plugin at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HipChat+Plugin. I'm using it with a v2 API token.